# Android Gdx: Sharing Content on Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, libgdx, share

Coding in Gdx is a bit challenging, I have developed an android game in gdx. Everything went smoothly except for the part of sharing content on Facebook, I really got stuck and I don't really know how to do it. I want to share the score and a link.

if anyone has an experience on this please help.

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing else than showing the Android share dialog. You can see an example on [how to implement platform specific code](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code) in the libGDX wiki page, and see the Android documentation on how to show the share dialog.

Comment: I have been through this but I am facing difficulty on how to implement it for sharing content on Facebook, would someone explain like an example?!